# javascript don't see function

Tags: javascript

I have a function in file.
`<script type="text/javascript" src="domain.com/js/script.js"></script>`

This is just script from head:

```
$(function($){
   function testFunc(obj) {
      obj.hide();
   }
});
```

In index.php:
`<li onclick="testFunc(this)">text</li>`

And nothing change, browser (Chrome) said:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: testFuncis not defined`

Comment: Why `$(function($){…})`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a scope issue, just remove the function from the `document.ready` block:

```
//$(function($){
    function testFunc(obj) {
       obj.hide();
    }
//});
```

When you define a function inside of another function, it will only be visible inside of that function.

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you. And one more question, now browser say me that "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'hide' "

Answer (score 4):

The better way to use jQuery to do this is:

```
$(function($){
    $('li').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

and remove the inline click handler you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is wrong. Replace the your javascript(mentioned above) with

```
    function testFunc(obj) {
        $(obj).hide();
    }
```

Comment: How is your answer any different from bfavaretto's?

Comment: @j08691: There is a difference. The OP had `obj.hide()`, as opposed to `$(obj).hide()`. The former won't work, since `obj` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.